# Fixing circular dependencies c++17 headers

Tags: c++, clang, forward-declaration

I am using a clang C++17 compiler and I am getting the warning:

```
declaration of 'struct Xchart' will not be visible outside of this function.
```

This warning is pointing to a function declaration that uses a structure that is declared in a different header file. I believe this is caused by circular dependencies in the two header files but I have not been able to resolve the warning

Header toolkit.h declares the function MyFunction which uses the structure Xchart as an input. This is where the warning points.

**toolkit.h**

```
#ifndef _TOOLKIT_H
#define _TOOLKIT_H 1

#define _WINDOWS 1
#include <windows.h>

short WINAPI MyFunction(struct Xchart *mychart ); <--Warning Here

#pragma pack(push, 1)
#pragma pack(pop)
#endif /*_TOOLTKIT_H */
```

Header mystruct.h declares the Xchart structure

**mystruct.h**

```
#ifndef _mystructs_h
#define _mystructs_h 1

#include "toolkit.h"

#pragma pack(push, 1)

struct Xchart { 
  int MyDays;   
  short LoadMe;   
  wchar_t MyLabel[100]; 
};

#pragma pack(pop)
#endif /* _mystructs_h */
```

Can you show how to change these two header files so the warning is resolved?

Comment: There is no circular dependency here. You just didn't declare `struct Xchart` anywhere before `short WINAPI MyFunction()`. So, do so in t`toolkit.h`: forward-declare with `struct Xchart;` before declaring said function. Or put the `struct` in its own header file and make the full definition available to both headers.

Comment: You have to reverse the header mystruct.h should be included to the toolkit.h. As you want to use the structure defined in mystruct.h.Remove the toolkit.h from my strict.h.

Comment: It looks like the header is included in, and compiled as C code. Your headers are well formed C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual fix is simple:

```
struct Xchart; // declares Xchart; definition is elsewhere.
short WINAPI MyFunction(Xchart *mychart); // Function declaration.
```

Only toolkit.cpp will need the definition of `Xchart`, but .cpp files themselves are not included elsewhere and don't contribute to circular inclusions.

Answer (score 0):

There are two different problem.

1) In below `struct` keyword is problematic here:

```
short WINAPI MyFunction(struct Xchart *mychart )
```

It should be like below `Xchart` should be declared before this:

```
short WINAPI MyFunction(Xchart *mychart )
```

Remove the keyword from declaration.

2) You have to reverse the header inclusion. mystruct.h should be included in the toolkit.h. As you want to use the structure defined in mystruct.h. Remove the toolkit.h from my strict.h.

Comment: Be aware that `#pragma once` is not standard C++ (even if supported by most compilers). The official alternative is `#ifndef .... #define .... #endif` protection.

Comment: Updated the answer